# E-commerce model design terminology

Tags: sql, database, design-patterns, database-design

A simple one. Given certain product, e.g. a *shirt* (definitions source [here](https://www.webgility.com/blog/product-attributes-options-and-variants-the-challenges/)), if...

- An `attribute` is just a characteristic like *color*, *size*, *type*, etc.
- An `option` is each of the **values** associated with certain **attribute**, like *red* or *blue* (regarding to the *color* attribute).
- And a `variation` is each combination of **attributes** and each **option** of that attribute like, *red shirt*...

How can I denote a "*property*" defined by the user himself during the shopping process, like when he fills an **input** with a **custom message** to be written on the shirt?? Is it an option or not?

How is it normally modelled during database design for e-commerce solutions?
Thanks.

Comment: Seems that "Message" is just another attribute, beside color and size ..., of this entity.

Comment: So in this case, would you implement the EAV pattern or another "simpler" approach for database design?

Comment: I am not sure about the implementation model. But, at the conceptual level (upon which the implementation should ultimately be based), message seems an attribute of the entity.